# Crawling with urllib2 and mechanize is throwing error to me

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize

I am crawling some sites using urllib2 and mechanize but some of them gives me error

When i crawl using **urlllib2** it gives me **HTTPError: HTTPError()**

Code for **urllib2**

```
import urllib2
response=urllib2.urlopen('http://proxygaz.com/country/india-proxy/').read()
```

**Error**

> HTTPError: HTTPError()

When i crawl using **mechanize** it gives me **httperror_seek_wrapper: >>**

Code for **mechanize**

```
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open('http://proxygaz.com/country/india-proxy/').read()
```

**Error**

> httperror_seek_wrapper: >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same error, try using a user-agent or `requests`:

```
import requests

response=requests.get('http://proxygaz.com/country/india-proxy/')
print(response.status_code)
200
```

using  agent-works fine:

```
import urllib2

resp = urllib2.Request('http://proxygaz.com/country/india-proxy/')
resp.add_header('User-Agent', 'FIREFOX')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
print  opener.open(resp).read()
```

Comment: I think you meant `request` rather than `resp`.

Comment: Well now, I'm getty petty, but you've created a `Request` object named `resp` (which I assume is "response").

Comment: @mhawke, the code works and does what it is supposed to I am not going to worry about variable names. Anyway you got your upvote so you should be happy also imitation is the highest form of flattery so thanks again ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the `urllib2.urlopen()` example, the exception is:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

For some reason you don't have permission to access the resource.... it's the user agent. It works with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or you can change the user agent as follows:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://proxygaz.com/country/india-proxy/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Your answer looks very familar

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  As does yours! Although there is some variation in style... and yours doesn't work :)

Comment: well I did have it down first ;)

Comment: Actually, no you didn't. You added the code after mine... not that it really matters... and you do have a NameError.

Comment: lol you have a good imagination, you actually did it yesterday also on a subprocess question,

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Not sure what to do if an answer overlaps in time with another answer, and those answers are correct. Should I bother to look at the solution for mechanize, or would I step on your toes again?